# Filter NULL in a gcloud query

Tags: filter, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

My question is how can I filter a column in GCP and get all NULL outputs.

For example, in the below picture I would like to filter all "NUM_NODES" which do not have any number (NULL)
[image]

Thanks in advance,
Yonatan Brand

Comment: What `gcloud` command are you running?  What platform are you running the `gcloud` command upon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the gcloud command with the [filter flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters). For instance:

```
gcloud container clusters list --filter="-currentNodeCount:*"
```